# Gradle task test fails with ConnectException: Could not connect to server

Tags: java, gradle, freebsd

When I run gradle test on my machine it works fine, but when i run it on our FreeBSD build server it fails with this exception:

```
 :alerting:testPicked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
    org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ConnectException: Could not connect to server [4ddcef47-2985-48dd-b83e-9eab161fe8a3 port:12526, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]]. Tried addresses: [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.connect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:68)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedClient.getConnection(MessageHubBackedClient.java:35)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:58)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:37)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.execute(ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.java:87)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.execute(ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:49)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:33)
    at jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:118)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.tryConnect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:82)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.connect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:55)
    ... 9 more
    FAILED
```

I thought that the problem is blocked loopback by firewall (we are running in a jail), but I can ping it and connect to other services running locally through loopback.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: check with tcpdump/wireshark what is send via the loopback interface

Comment: I am having the same problem on a host that does not have a valid localhost setup. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I forced our admin to make valid localhost for this jail. Not really great solution.